# VisualSVN Server self-signed certificate

Tags: security, web-server, ssl-certificate, visualsvn-server

I asked this question in StackOverflow site but nobody can answer it. I will try here:

I am reading VisualSVN doc online and one of them is like this:

```
   It's also possible to export a self-signed certificate from VisualSVN Server 
and save this certificate in the trusted certificates list on all client computers.
```

but cannot find more info about how to do that. anybody can help me? I am learning how to use SVN and will share with my brothers first. We are using Windows XP.
thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default VisualSVN creates a self-signed certificate which you can use. Using Internet Explorer for example just open up the VisualSVN site (https://yourserver/svn).  After logging in there is a "Certificate Error" button next to the address bar.  Left click on that button and then select "View Certificates" at the bottom.  This will open the certificate properties dialog.  At the bottom you can install the certificate.

If you want the certificate to pre-install click on the details tab and use the Copy to File... button. You can then used the generated .cer file to install the certificate on other computers.